# Difference between FooTarget.cmake and FindFoo.cmake?

Tags: cmake

CMake automatically creates a `FooTarget.cmake` file by e.g. adding

```
install(EXPORT FooTargets
  FILE FooTargets.cmake
  NAMESPACE Foo::
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/Foo
)
```

into the `CMakeLists.txt` of a library named Foo. What's the difference between `FooTargets.cmake` and `FindFoo.cmake`? With the above snippet, `FooTarget.cmake` is automatically installed by running `sudo make install` in the build directory.

However, it seems like such a library isn't necessarily found with `find_package(Foo)`. What's the point of this `FooTarget.cmake` file if it doesn't make the library automatically discoverable? Since the library is generated by CMake it would seem like CMake itself should know how to generate the `FindFoo.cmake` library that makes the library automatically discoverable by other projects using CMake and put it where it should go on the platform.

Answer (score 2):

Discovering a package by using `find_package(Foo)` consists in two steps:

1. Using [predefined algorithm](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/find_package.html#search-procedure), `find_package` locates a script `FooConfig.cmake` describing the package `Foo`.
2. The script `FooConfig.cmake` is processed by CMake in the context of the main project (which calls `find_package`).

This script sets variables and/or *IMPORTED* targets, which can be used further by the main project.

The script `FooTarget.cmake` generated by CMake helps in the second step. This script is intended to be included (with `include()`) into `FooConfig.cmake`. When `FooTarget.cmake` is processed by CMake, it creates *IMPORTED* targets and sets their properties.

So, the very basic `FooConfig.cmake` script contains just a single line:

```
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/FooTarget.cmake")
```

and installed using `install(FILES)` into the directory where `find_package` could locate the script (a directory `lib/cmake/Foo` perfectly fits for this purpose).

Such simple content of the `FooConfig.cmake` script implies it to be installed near the `FooTarget.cmake` script included into it.

More complex `FooConfig.cmake` script could process `COMPONENTS` request of `find_package`, define functions/macros usable by the main project and so on. Examples of that script could be found in [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-a-package-configuration-file).